# Haskell Convert Integer to Int?

Tags: haskell, types, casting, integer

Is it possible to cast an `Integer` to an `Int`? The other direction is possible: `toInteger`. I know that `Integer` is able to store bigger values, but sometimes a conversation is needed to use functions in the standard library. I tried `(n :: Int)` and other code samples I found - but nothing works.

```
takeN :: Integer -> [a] -> [a]
takeN n l = take n l
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use `fromIntegral`.

```
takeN :: Integer -> [a] -> [a]
takeN n l = take (fromIntegral n) l
```

Note that `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`, so sometimes you will need an extra type annotation (e.g. `(fromIntegral n :: Int)`), but usually the compiler can infer which type you want.

In the special case of your example, in `Data.List` there is `genericTake :: (Integral i) => i -> [a] -> [a]`, which does the same thing as `take` but with a more general type.

Answer (score 20):

there is also `fromInteger` (`fromIntegral` is just `fromInteger . toInteger`, but since you have an `Integer` anyway so you can skip the second part)