# Casting Integer to Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, integer, int, integral

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell Convert Integer to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964766/haskell-convert-integer-to-int)

I have a function to calculate a birthYear

```
birthYear :: Int -> Int
birthYear age = currentYear - age

currentYear :: Integral -> Integral
currentYear year = year
```

How do I cast the Integral type to an Int so birthYear can work?

FYI, age is fixed as an Int as it is coming from IO and I am using the read (age) function to convert from String to Int.

Comment: @nponecoop It's a good match on title, but I suspect the underlying perplexity may be different.

Answer (score 3):

First, you cannot use `Integral` (which is a type class) as a type. You probably meant:

```
birthYear :: Int -> Int
birthYear age = currentYear - age

currentYear :: Integral a => a
currentYear = 2011
```

And this just works. Or if you want to have:

```
currentYear :: Integral a => a -> a
currentYear year = year
```

Then this also works:

```
birthYear :: Int -> Int
birthYear age = (currentYear 2011) - age
```

`Int` is an instance of `Integral` so you do not have to "cast" anything.

Comment: I can't really do that as year is coming from another function which generates the year as type Integral. That is being passed into the currentYear function and then to the birthYear function to calculate the age. As a result none of those ideas work.

Comment: Maybe you should then post your real code? Because above definition of `birthYear` is simply wrong. You subtract `age` from a function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers

From this:

> Integral types are ones which may only contain whole numbers and not
>   fractions. Int (fixed-size machine integers) and Integer (arbitrary
>   precision integers) are the two Integral types in the standard Haskell
>   libraries. The workhorse for converting types is fromIntegral, which
>   will convert any integral type into any numeric type (e.g.Rational,
>   Double, Int16...):

```
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
```

Comment: See I tried using the fromIntegral function so it becomes:

birthYear age = fromIntegral (currentYear) - age

but I am getting the error:

No instance for (Integral (Integer -> Integer)) arising from a use of fromIntegral at ...

Comment: @StuartPaton: Because `currentYear` is a function, not an `Integral` value.  Use `fromIntegral` on the result of applying `currentYear`, or compose them.

Comment: @StuartPaton The error message suggests (to me, anyway) that you may be confusing the `Integer` type (of arbitrarily large numbers) and the `Integral` type class (which collects representations of integers, bounded or otherwise). You might want to think about what `birthYear` needs as inputs in order to tell the year of birth. I mean, I used to be 17, but if you don't know what year I was 17 in, then you can't figure out when I was born.